# Understanding the computation graph of Tensorflow Keras layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, linear-regression

I've created the simplest Dense layer with just 2 parameters (kernel and bias with 1 parameter each):

```
network1d = tf.keras.Sequential()
layer1d = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=[1], activation=None)
network1d.add(layer1d)
network1d.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And this is the graph drawn by Tensorboard:
[image]

I don't think I'm understanding the major pieces - in particular, is my model (with the two parameters) the red "dense" block, or the one near the bottom of the graph? (The one in the Adam has red border because I clicked on it.)